Dinamically reposition buttons on image using Sveltekit and tailwind
I have created an html map by declaring an array
<script>
  let areas = [
    { shape: 'rect', left: '4.94%', top: '60.55%', width: '7.28%', height: '22.78%', title: 'EVK30-200', id: 1 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '19%', top: '60.72%', width: '6.97%', height: '22.45%', title: 'EVK30-200', id: 2 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '32.81%', top: '60.72%', width: '7.09%', height: '22.45%', title: 'EVK30-200', id: 3 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '46.61%', top: '60.72%', width: '6.97%', height: '22.61%', title: 'EVK30-200', id: 4 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '74.48%', top: '60.89%', width: '6.84%', height: '22.45%', title: 'EVK30-200', id: 5 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '18.37%', top: '25.46%', width: '3.17%', height: '15.58%', title: 'EVK14-40-T', id: 6 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '25.4%', top: '25.96%', width: '1.9%', height: '11.31%', title: 'EVK10-30-T', id: 7 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '31.6%', top: '26.05%', width: '2.09%', height: '11.39%', title: 'EVK10-30-T', id: 8 },
    { shape: 'rect', left: '37.94%', top: '26.13%', width: '2.22%', height: '11.47%', title: 'EVK10-30-T', id: 9 },
    { shape: 'circle', left: '44.97%', top: '38.69%', width: '3.1%', height: '4.44%', title: 'screw_1', id: 10, isScrew: true },
    { shape: 'circle', left: '53.7%', top: '36.18%', width: '3.36%', height: '3.43%', title: 'screw_2', id: 11, isScrew: true },
  ];
<script/>

and I calculate the coordinates in an onMount() function. In that istance, I also create a button for each area calculated:
<script>
  onMount(() => {
    const container = document.querySelector('.map-container');

    areas.forEach(area => {
      const coords = area.coords.split(',').map(coord => parseInt(coord.trim()));

      const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.classList.add('tooltip');
      wrapper.classList.add('absolute', 'group');
      wrapper.setAttribute('data-tip', area.title);

      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.classList.add('btn');
      button.classList.add('variant-ghost', 'rounded-none', 'pointer-events-auto', 'group-hover:block', 'hidden', 'w-full', 'h-full');
      button.addEventListener('click', () => passData(area));
      wrapper.appendChild(button);

      wrapper.style.left = area.left;
      wrapper.style.top = area.top;
      wrapper.style.width = area.width;
      wrapper.style.height = area.height;

      if (area.shape === 'circle') {
        wrapper.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        button.classList.remove('rounded-none');
      }

      container.appendChild(wrapper);

      // Recalculate map coord every 500ms
      ImageMap('img[usemap]', 500);
    });
  });
<script/>

I also styled the .map-container as relative.
At the end, I render everything using a {#each} block:
<div class="flex">
  <div class="map-container">
    <img src="../src/images/pdu-kitting-step.png" usemap="#image-map" id="map-image" alt="PDU Kitting" width="1579px" height="1194px" />
    <map name="image-map">
      {#each areas as area}
        <area shape={area.shape} coords={area.coords} href={area.href} alt={area.alt} />
      {/each}
    </map>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-16 flex-1">
    <SideData />
  </div>
</div>
 

The issue is that, if I resize the viewport or the image, the positions of the buttons are not aligned with the map.
Is it possible to fix that?

You should not directly manipulate the DOM, creating elements in the script. The whole point of Svelte is to not have to do any of that.

Okay, I'll try a different approach. Thanks

onMount only runs once, if you need to react to layout changes, use a ResizeObserver.
Instead of creating elements in the script, use the HTML template language. You can still calculate intermediate state as necessary in the script; if the base data can change as well, use a reactive statement in addition to the observer to trigger updates/calculations.

i created a function that gets called by ResizeObserver and now it works flawlessly. thanks again for the help
